# Aframe: getting vertices of any object

Tags: three.js, aframe

Is there a way we can get the vertices of an object in a scene. This is either for a primitive or for a loaded model. For example

```
<a-entity geometry='primitive:box' rotation='0 30 0'></a-entity>
```

or

```
<a-entity gltf-model='#model'></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For geometry, defaults to buffer attributes (vertices in array) contained in:

```
el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry.attributes
```

To get easier to manage, set to non-buffer (`geometry="primitive: box; buffer: false"`) and get from:

```
el.getObject3D('mesh').geometry.vertices
```

For gltf-model, it also has a geometr(ies) (buffer geometry):

```
el.getObject3D('mesh').traverse(node => {
  if (node.geometry) {
    // node.geometry.attributes...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ngokevin. Possibly in the case of gltf I will have to get a bounded-box before I get the vertices. Should be able to move ahead. Thanks